# biblatex not omitting shortauthor with repeating authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I added support for shortauthors in biblatex authoryear. When one author has multiple entries authorname is omitted, but not shortauthor. How can I fix that?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6EA8.png)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{filecontents}{filename.bib} 
@Electronic{ilo2015,
  Title                    = {World Employment and Social Outlook},
  Author                   = {{Internationale Arbeitsorganisation}},
  Shortauthor              = {ILO},
}
@Electronic{ilo2013,
  Title                    = {Beschaftigung, Wachstum und soziale Gerechtigkeit. Bericht des Generaldirektors.},
  Author                   = {{Internationale Arbeitsorganisation}},
  Shortauthor              = {ILO},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

% Show shortauthor
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
        {}
        {\printnames{shortauthor}%
         \addspace\textendash\space}}

\addbibresource{filename.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the sources of biblatex-authoryear I found that `\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}` is the solution

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}{}
    {\printnames{shortauthor}%
    \addspace\textendash\space}}
}
```